# Copying a portion of a string using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I have to get username from MeetingItem.Recipient, I tried following to get it:
`CStr(MeetingItem.Recipient.Address)` and got this responce:
`"/o=POST/ou=Zuerich/cn=Recipients/cn=eicherr"` I have to do loop through all 
recipients and get usernames for example if i do loor with code above Ill get:

`"/o=POST/ou=Zuerich/cn=Recipients/cn=eicherr"`
`"/o=POST/ou=Group (FYHF23PDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=kisslingie0e"`
`"/o=POST/ou=Group (FYHF23PDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=katzensteink"`
`"/O=POST/OU=Bern/cn=Recipients/cn=junkerb"`
`"/o=POST/ou=Group (FYHF23PDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=tanzg6a7"`

I need  only last part of this strings, how can i do that?

**note:** kisslingie0e and tanzg6a7 this nicknames contains at the end unnecessary three characters that must also be avoided

Or is there another way to get usernames from `MeetingItem.Recipient.Adress`.
To get Email I did following:

```
For Each recip In recips

    'Obtain the E-mail Address of a Recipient
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
    Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor

    Dim email as String
    email = CStr(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS))
    Debug.Print email

End For
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress` to get the SMTP address.
Be prepared to handle nulls and errors.

To get the NT login name (domain account), read the `PR_ACCOUNT` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A00001F`) using `Recipient.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.

You can also use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Alias`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko this is what I need. Thank you very much.  `.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Alias` gives te right value

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove the leading text is to reverse the string and loop until you find a "/":

```
Dim email As String, username As String
Dim i As Integer

email = "/o=POST/ou=Group (FYHF23PDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=kisslingie0e"

'Reverse string
email = StrReverse(email)

'Loop through string until / is found
For i = 1 To Len(email) Step 1
    If Mid(email, i, 1) = "/" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        username = username & Mid(email, i, 1)
    End If
Next i

'Reverse username
username = StrReverse(username)
```

If you need to remove the "cn=", do something like this:

```
username = Split(username, "=")(1)
```

If the usernames never contain any numbers, you could remove the trail like this:

```
For i = 1 To Len(username) Step 1
    'Loop until a number occurs
    If IsNumeric(Mid(username, i, 1)) Then
        'Use string until the number
        username = Mid(username, 1, i - 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: it almost works for me, how can I remove last 3 characters if username contains numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion that works IF the source is consistent in having "Recipients/cn=" just prior to the desired string, it is followed by optionally stripping the last characters if they are numeric in the third or second to last character.

```
    'find the location of constant, set vEM
    vLoc = InStr(email, "Recipients/cn=")
    vEM = Mid(email, vLoc + 14, 50)
    'Check if third to last or second to last character is numeric
    vOffset = 0
    If IsNumeric(Mid(vEM, Len(vEM) - 2, 1)) Then
       vOffset = 3
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(vEM, Len(vEM) - 1, 1)) Then
       vOffset = 2
    Else
       vOffset = 0
    End If
    vEM = Left(vEM, Len(vEM) - vOffset)
```